# I have a script that loops through rows of a file and picks out certain rows to

Tags: python

write to new files, however, it only works for the first newly created file. It then returns the other newly created files but with no rows written to them. Help please!

Here is my code:

```
with open('path to file') as csvfile:
    readCSVstations = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for i in range(len(lat)):

    with open("path to new file/cap_" + str(lat[i]) + "_" + str(lon[i]) + ".dat", 'w') as f:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')

    for row in readCSVstations:
        p1_lat=float(lat[i])
        p1_lon=float(lon[i])

        p2_lat=float(row[2])
        p2_lon=float(row[3])

        p1=(p1_lat,p1_lon)
        p2=(p2_lat,p2_lon)
```

lat and long are just lists of lat and long values

```
            x=(vincenty(p1,p2)).kilometers

            if x <= 250:

                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: is `x <= 250` ever true? remove the condition and see what happens

Comment: can you add the first lines of your csv plz?

Comment: Hi guys, solved it now thanks! The initial open for reading had to be done inside the loop is all, cheers